# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? in visual studio code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

Below is the configuration in vscode.
Although I have configured JDK in vscode, I am still getting the compilation error when I run maven install but maven test is working fine..

Please advise me how to resolve.

[image]

Comment: Once you are in a terminal, what matters is what is available in your PATH (not in vscode); from a terminal, what does `java -version`  say?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder it says, "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)   "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not configure `"maven.terminal.useJavaHome"`, it depends on `java.home`, but `java.home` is deprecated for now.

[Official docs](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#project-jdks):

> If you need to compile your projects against a different JDK version,
> it's recommended you configure the java.configuration.runtimes
> property in your user settings, eg:
>
> ```
> "java.configuration.runtimes": [
>   {
>     "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
>     "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "JavaSE-11",
>     "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "JavaSE-18",
>     "path": "/path/to/jdk-18",
>     "default": true
>   },
> ]
> ```

But it will not modify the `Path` environment variable in the terminal, it will affect the Java extension, for example, the `Run Java` button.

And from the picture in your question and your comments, you need to download and install a JDK first and remember to add the bin folder of JDK to the `Path` environment variable.